# cURL returns please enable cookies?

Tags: php, curl, cookies

It seems like I need some help to set up my cURL, I am trying to do API calls to an external website from my server.
What bugs me is that sometimes this code works and return the expected result, but sometimes It returns this message :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
$path_cookie = 'cookie.txt';
if (!file_exists(realpath($path_cookie))) touch($path_cookie);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/api/findusers/".$nick_list."?key=".$voobly_key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($path_cookie));
$headers = [
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
        'cookie: __cfduid=d0d14dfd36e0da8e7858b58873b4263181523751395'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "rep : $response";
```

Is the problem on my side or the problem could come from the external server?

My cookie.txt looks like this :

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.example.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1555287395  __cfduid    d0d14dfd36e0da8e7858b58873b4263181523751395
```

Comment: Does it work if you access it directly from your browser?

Comment: yes It does.. that's why I think the problem is on my side

Comment: Maybe the server is checking for headers that are usually sent from a browser, try sending them.

Comment: how do I know what headers are required? do you have a list?

Comment: Set the `User-agent` header. You can view headers sent in the request by going to the _Network_ tab in your developers tools.

Comment: The 500 error you get, is it from the API or in your side? if it's in your side enable errors display or check your error logs

Comment: lol it was my bad, I accidently deleted a right parenthesis, but the header still doesn't fix my problem

Comment: This is the [CloudFlare CAPTCHA Challenge Page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203366080-Why-do-I-see-a-captcha-or-challenge-page-Attention-Required-trying-to-visit-a-site-protected-by-CloudFlare-as-a-site-visitor-)

Comment: maybe you exceeded the daily limit (1000 from their documentation). @drew010 I don't think this is the CAPTCHA cloudflare shows.

Comment: I am far from 1000 try haha! And sometimes it is working, and sometimes not... Here is the request header from my browser :  http://prntscr.com/j5dhif

Comment: I added the content of my cookie.txt, can see I get something

Comment: use https://anti-captcha.com/

Comment: I don't even see the captcha, so how can I bypass it?

Comment: @MehdiBounya It is, but without any CSS or external resources loaded.  At least it has all the same text as https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cloudflare+captcha&t=lm&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2F9Eu0v.png

Comment: And since he leaked the address of the site in the screenshot, it shows that it's DNS is set to Cloudflare and the IP's resolve to CF addresses :)  Since the site does have a public API, they should exclude that path from the protection but that's an issue with the site so OP should be contacting their support.

Comment: @drew010 You are right, I only remember the layout of the Cloudflare CAPTCHA thing and not the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well their cloudflare system was just blocking the IP of my server (it was a shared one), getting a new host with its own IP solved the issue... 
Thank you for your time guys, appreciated it.

Answer (score 7):

curl has a full cookie "engine" built in.
If you activate it, you can have curl receive and send cookies like a browser does.

> Command line options:
>
> ```
> -b, --cookie
> ```
>
> tell curl a file to read cookies from and start the cookie engine, or
>   if it isn't a file it will pass on the given string. -b name=var works
>   and so does -b cookiefile.
>
> ```
> -j, --junk-session-cookies
> ```
>
> when used in combination with -b, it will skip all "session cookies"
>   on load so as to appear to start a new cookie session.
>
> ```
> -c, --cookie-jar
> ```
>
> tell curl to start the cookie engine and write cookies to the given
>   file after the request(s)

Ref: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html

Comment: I'm not sure how is this related to PHP cURL

Comment: Sorry, you may want to try that instead: https://github.com/agusl88/VooblyAPI-PHP-Wrapper

Comment: Can you give command-line usage examples for each option?