# Cloudflare blocking PHP CURL request from AWS EC2 (CPANEL)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, cloudflare

I am trying to send a request to an API which is having cloudflare configured, i am getting this result -

[image]

I tried all things like CURL, HTTP_Request2, file_get_contents() function but not working, this script is working on other servers/hosting providers and also working through postman but not on my AWS EC2 instance, it is telling me to enable cookies but am not sure how to do that. Please help me fix this problem.

Here is my CURL code -

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://smmpython.com/api/v2?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&action=balance',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cURL returns please enable cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837132/curl-returns-please-enable-cookies)

Comment: If you have not already done so you MUST recycle the API key you accidentally added to this question you are opening yourself up to compromise!!

Comment: @Raptor i tried making a new EC2 instance with a different IP but still same problem, i think there should be some config in the EC2 itself

Comment: Did you contact Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly a security measure implemented by CloudFare. Image a bunch of IP addresses calling CloudFare, it might trigger DDoS for a minor application. Here are some suggestions:

- Attach Elastic IP (EIP) with your EC2 instance
- If that doesn't work then you can contact CloudFare support to enable traffic from specific IP (Whitelisting)
- And as an added step check with AWS support if they have any specific solution for this